# Vue v-text-field rules not applying properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have multiple v-text-field 's with corresponding validations. When the submit button is clicked the rules are applying fine, but when the validators are triggered on mouse left, the rule that is applied to the v-text-field is not applied, instead the rule defined for the first control of same type i.e., first v-text-field is applied to this control. Company Name text-box is showing Title is required. For some reason the form-wizard is taking the first control rules instead of the rules defined on itself.

```js
var signUpModal = new Vue({

    el: "#registerModal",
    data: () =>({                 
            companyName: "",
            companyNameRules: [
                (v) => !!v || "Company Name is required"
            ],           
            advisorTitle: "",
            advisorTitleRules: [
                (v) => !!v || "Title is required"
            ],
        type:2
    }),
    
    template:
        `<div>
            <template class="container-fluid" style="padding-top:74px;" id="IDWarningMessage">
                <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content" style="overflow-y: hidden">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="registerModalID">Register</h5> <button type="button"
                                    class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span
                                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body" style="background-color:#F5F5F5;overflow-y:scroll;height:50rem">                            
                                 
                                    <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete" 
                                                 @on-loading="setLoading"
                                                 @on-validate="handleValidation"
                                                 @on-error="handleErrorMessage"
                                                 color="#266FAF"
                                                 error-color="#e74c3c"
                                                 @on-change="handleTabChange">
                                      <template slot="step" scope="props">
                                        <wizard-step :tab="props.tab"
                                        :transition="props.transition"
                                        :key="props.tab.title"
                                        :index="props.index">
                                        </wizard-step>
                                      </template>                                                                                
                                      <tab-content title="Register" :before-change="validateRegisterAsync">
                                        <v-form ref="advisorForm" v-model="validAdvisor" v-if="type == 1 ">
                                                <v-container>                                                    
                                                    <v-layout row>
                                                        <v-flex>
                                                            <v-text-field name="advisor" v-model="advisorTitle" :rules="advisorTitleRules" label="Advisor Title" required :error-messages="errorMessages"></v-text-field>
                                                        </v-flex>
                                                    </v-layout>
                                                    </v-container>
                                         </v-form>                                             
                                      <v-form ref="companyForm" v-model="company" v-if="type == 2">
                                                <v-container>                                                    
                                                    <v-layout row>
                                                        <v-flex>
                                                            <v-text-field v-model="companyName" :rules="companyNameRules" label="Company Name" :error-messages="errorMessages" required></v-text-field>
                                                        </v-flex>
                                                    </v-layout>                                                         
                                                </v-container>
                                         </v-form>                                                                               
                                       </tab-content>                                                                           
                                 </form-wizard>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>`,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing v-if to v-show resolved the issue